# SSRS Stacked Area and Line Chart showing Gap between Dates

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a line chart that is showing a series for the stack area. I have nulls for my data for a few months in a row which shows a gap in the chart which what I want a cliff. But when the chart resumes with non null data the chart starts from 0 and shoots up to the number lets say 98 in this case. How or which properties do I need to adjust in the chart that when I resume I can start off at 98 instead of 0 and climbing up to 98.

[image: chartissue]

Comment: Pictures of your current situation and desired output would be most beneficial here

Comment: @Jonnus http://i64.tinypic.com/alsokz.png

Comment: Are you forced to use a stacked area, instead of a stacked column?

Comment: @Jonnus I posted a pic of what I am trying to resolve, I am trying to get rid of that area (circled red) where it starts back up from 0, I want to restart at 2. This is dummy data with two series on the chart, the blanks between are nulls from the sp. I got rid of the first drop by setting the fill expression on series 2 to =IIF(Fields!s1.Value="", "#00ffffff", "#00000000")

Comment: to be clear what I am trying to do is that when data comes back and the value is null, I dont want it to drop to 0 it should just stop, and pick up at the value given as weel in this case it should stop at 5 and 2 and restart at 5 and 2

Comment: I saw the picture and understood your problem - that triangle does not belong.  I was trying to work out why you were using stacked area instead of stacked column for your data, and understand the reasoning behind that decision (as stacked column would not exhibit this problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using a Stacked Area chart you could use a Stacked Column chart.  For the data series you wish to be visible view the properties of the series, and under `CustomAttributes` set `PointWidth` to be 1.1.

When rendered this will then look like as below

[image]